# Exception when returning Task vs returning awaited result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

My understanding is that if you have an `async` method where the only `await` is the finally return of a `Task`, you can remove the `async` and `await` keywords and just return the `Task`.

For example:

```
public async Task<object> Handle(object message)
{
    var result = await Task.FromResult(message);
    return result;
}
```

becomes

```
public Task<object> Handle(object message)
{
    return Task.FromResult(message);
}
```

However this doesn't appear to work when the method contains multiple await statements.

For example:

```
async Task Main()
{
    // outputs: Request
    var requestHandlerAwaitingResult = (Request) await new HandlerAwaitingResult().Handle(new Request());
    Debug.WriteLine(requestHandlerAwaitingResult.Description);

    // InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]' to type 'Request'.
    var requestHandlerReturnTask = (Request) await new HandlerReturningTask().Handle(new Request());
    Debug.WriteLine(requestHandlerReturnTask.Description);
}

public class Request
{
    public string Description = "Request";
}

public class HandlerAwaitingResult
{
    public async Task<object> Handle(object message)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        var result = await Task.FromResult(message);
        return result;
    }
}

public class HandlerReturningTask
{
    public async Task<object> Handle(object message)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        return Task.FromResult(message);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

Fundamentally, what is the difference between

```
public class HandlerReturningTask
{
    public async Task<object> Handle(object message)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        return Task.FromResult(message);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class HandlerReturningTask
{
    public async Task<object> Handle(object message)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        return await Task.FromResult(message);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class HandlerReturningTask
{
    public Task<object> Handle(object message)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your understanding of state machine compiler creates for async methods can you please explain first why it should work from your point of view

Comment: I agree with the previous comment, and don't understand what you are asking. As you are (should be) aware, an `async` method's `return` statement returns the object of the type `T` in the `Task<T>`. In your `HandlerReturningTask`, `T` is `object`. Then this object is unwrapped by the `await`. So, you return a `Task<Result>` object and try to cast it to `Result`. Why _should_ that work? Instead of `return Task.FromResult(message);`, why would you not just `return message;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand the question. But based on your edit:

> Fundamentally, what is the difference between […`return Task.FromResult(message);`…] and […`return await Task.FromResult(message);`…]

It is important to understand what `await` does: it represents a point in your method where the method can return, and then execution in the method can resume later when the "awaitable" (e.g. a `Task`) completes.

If the `Task` is a `Task<T>`, then the other thing `await` does is, on resuming execution in the method, unwrap the `T` value for the `Task<T>` object, i.e. get its `Result` property value. The `await` expression evaluations to that value.

Finally, for `async Task<T>` methods the `return` statement causes the `Task<T>` object returned by the method (at the first `await` expression) to have the `Result` value in the `return {value}` expression.

So in your example, `return Task.FromResult(message);` causes the `Task<object>.Result` property to have the value of an object of type `Task<Request>`. Later, the `await` expression evaluates this object's `Result` property value and you try to cast this to an object of type `Request`, which of course is illegal.

Using `return await Task.FromResult(message);` causes the `await` expression first to be evaluated (so the `return` statement can return the result of that expression), which has the effect of getting the `Task<Request>.Result` property value. This value is then returned by the `return` statement, causing the awaited `Task<object>.Result` value to be the `Request` object originally passed to the method. This, of course, *can* be cast back to the type `Request`, when unwrapped by the `await` in the caller.

That said, typically you'd just return the value directly. Wrapping it in a `Task<T>` object only to then immediately unwrap it with an `await` expression is pointless. Writing `return message;` in that scenario would have exactly the same result, but with more readable and more efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

The generated state machine handles any awaitable. Not only tasks.

If you're dealing with only one task, you can bypass the overhead of the computer-generated state machine. In the case of an exception, however, the stack trace won't be what you might expect.

The return type of async methods will always be task of whatever you're returning.